# In Windows, R seems to call the wrong format function

Tags: r, windows, format

I'm trying to run the same R script in Windows (R version 3.2.0) and on a Mac (R version 3.1.3). It works on the Mac, but when I'm trying to use this command

```
startYear <- format(min(dates), "%Y")
```

in Windows, I get the following error message:

```
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid 'trim'argument
```

It seems to be calling the wrong format function...

Is there a way to tell it that it's the date format function I want? I already tried

```
Date.format()
```

but it just says that `Date.format()` doesn't exist!

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

PS: I can't just stop using Windows, so I have to get it working there.

Comment: Please provide the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question, when you get the error message. A simple workaround would be `base::format(min(dates), "%Y")`.

Comment: Did you mean to try `format.Date` instead of `Date.format` ?

Comment: Your problem is not caused by using windows. There must be something else (e.g., you defined a `format` function, which masks `base::format`). Try it with a vanilla R session.